# Recursive function to obtain non-repeated characters from string

Tags: python, string, list, recursion

I have this exercise:

> Write a recursive function that takes a string and returns all the characters that are not repeated in said string.
>
> The characters in the output don't need to have the same order as in the input string.

First I tried this, but given the condition for the function to stop, it never evaluates the last character:

```
i=0
lst = []

def list_of_letters_rec(str=""):
    if str[i] not in lst and i < len(str) - 1:
        lst.append(str[i])
        list_of_letters_rec(str[i+1:])
    elif str[i] in lst and i < len(str) - 1:
        list_of_letters_rec(str[i+1:])
    elif i > len(str) - 1:
        return lst
    
    return lst

word = input(str("Word?"))

print(list_of_letters_rec(word))
```

The main issue with this function is that it never evaluates the last character.
An example of an output:

`['a', 'r', 'd', 'v']` for input 'aardvark'.

Since the characters don't need to be ordered, I suppose a better approach would be to do the recursion backwards, and I also tried another approach (below), but no luck:

```
lst = []
def list_of_letters_rec(str=""):
    n = len(str) - 1
    if str[n] not in lst and n >= 0:
        lst.append(str[n])
        list_of_letters_rec(str[:n-1])
    elif str[n] in lst and n >= 0:
        list_of_letters_rec(str[:n-1])
    return lst

word = input(str("Word?"))

print(list_of_letters_rec(word))
```

Apparently, the stop conditions are not well defined, especially in the last one, as the output I get is

> IndexError: string index out of range

Could you give me any hints to help me correct the stop condition, either in the 1<sup>st</sup> or 2<sup>nd</sup> try?

Comment: Your code has references to undefined variables `lst` and `lista`...

Comment: @trincot Thanks! I'm not a native English speaker so the code was a bit 'adapted' from how it was originally. Already corrected that bit.

Comment: You shouldn't give variables the same names as commonly used built-in functions i.e.s should not call your string `str`.

Comment: There is still `lst`... where is it defined?

Comment: @trincot just before the function, already edited that bit too.

Comment: @DarrylG thanks for the heads-up, going to keep that in mind.

Comment: **`['a', 'r', 'd', 'v']` instead of `aardvark`.** - what was the input?

Comment: I think that OP means "for input 'aardvark'"

Comment: There is a mistake in the logic you are using, but the reason you are getting the input out of range in the second version is because you call `str[n]` BEFORE checking `n>=0`. If you just swap those two statements the program will run (Altough the output is still incorrect).

Comment: Why are you referencing a variable outside the function i.e. `lst` in this case.  Makes the function overly complicated and is generally bad form.

Comment: @DarrylG I wanted to have a variable for an empty list to save the output, but didn't want it to be set to empty every time that I called the function.

Comment: @PedroLobito yes I meant I got that output after the input 'aardvark'.

Comment: @Seppeke thanks for pointing out the mistake in my 2nd attempt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- You miss the last character because of `i < len(str) - 1` in the conditionals. That should be `i < len(str)` (but read the next points, as this still needs change)
- The test for `if i > len(str) - 1` should come first, before doing anything else, otherwise you'll get an invalid index reference. This also makes the other conditions on the length unnecessary.
- Don't name your variable `str`, as that is already a used name for the string type.
- Don't populate a list that is global. By doing this, you can only call the function once reliably. Any next time the list will still have the result of the previous call, and you'll be adding to that. Instead use the list that you get from the recursive call. In the base case, return an empty list.
- The global `i` has no use, since you never change its value; it is always 0. So you should just reference index `[0]` and check that the string is not empty.

Here is your code with those corrections:

```
def list_of_letters_rec(s=""):
    if not s:
        return []
    result = list_of_letters_rec(s[1:])
    if s[0] not in result:
        result.append(s[0])
    return result

print(list_of_letters_rec("aardvark"))
```

NB: This is not the most optimal way to do it. But I guess this is what you are asked to do.

Comment: Great answer and advice.

Comment: @trincot thank you so much!! :) I appreciated especially the advice on defining the stop condition and the variables correctly. I ended up managing to make my code work but with nested ifs, so your code is much simpler / better.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
word = input("> ")
result = [l for l in word if word.count(l) < 2]
```

---

```
>  aabc
['b', 'c']
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/548a87d865)

Comment: Note OP constraint: "Have an exercise that requires me to do a **recursive function** "

Comment: It's just an example, the OP can convert it to a recursive function.

Comment: @PedroLobito--I didn't down-vote.  I thought your answer was a great example of a non-recursive solution.

Comment: @PedroLobito thank you so much for your answer! Even if not recursive it is a really simple way to solve the problem and it will definitely help me. By the way I also did not downvote (don't even have enough rep to be able to do that).

Answer (score 1):

One improvement I would offer on @trincot's answer is the use of a `set`, which has better look-up time, *O(1)*, compared to lists, *O(n)*.

1. if the input string, `s`, is empty, return the empty result
2. (inductive) `s` has at least one character. if the first character, `s[0]` is in the memo, `mem`, the character has already been seen. Return the result of the sub-problem, `s[1:]`
3. (inductive) The first character is *not* in the memo. Add the first character to the memo and prepend the first character to the result of the sub-problem, `s[1:]`

```py
def list_of_letters(s, mem = set()):
  if not s:
    return ""                                           #1
  elif s[0] in mem:
    return list_of_letters(s[1:], mem)                  #2
  else:
    return s[0] + list_of_letters(s[1:], {*mem, s[0]})  #3

print(list_of_letters("aardvark"))
```

```
ardvk
```

Per your comment, the exercise asks only for a string as input. We can easily modify our program to privatize `mem` -

```py
def list_of_letters(s):                         # public api
  def loop(s, mem):                             # private api
    if not s:
      return ""
    elif s[0] in mem:
      return loop(s[1:], mem)
    else:
      return s[0] + loop(s[1:], {*mem, s[0]})
  return loop(s, set())                         # run private func

print(list_of_letters("aardvark"))              # mem is invisible to caller
```

```
ardvk
```

Python's native `set` data type accepts an iterable which solves this problem instantly. However this doesn't teach you anything about recursion :D

```py
print("".join(set("aardvark")))
```

```
akdrv
```

Comment: Although I think the original exercise requested the use of only a string variable as input / output, this is a very welcome input / suggestion of improvement. It was also explained very clearly. Thank you so much, @Thank you!!

Comment: I'm happy to help. I made an edit that shows how you can make `mem` invisible to the caller

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution would be to just use an index instead of splicing the string:

```
def list_of_letters_rec(string="", index = 0, lst = []):
    if(len(string) == index):
        return lst
    char = string[index]
    if  string.count(char) == 1:
        lst.append(char)
    return list_of_letters_rec(string, index+1, lst)
word = input(str("Word?"))
print(list_of_letters_rec(word))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I think the exercise meant to only have one input, the string, but it's really interesting to see another approach, and it helped learn a little more too! :)